# How to query information from NFS Server from Windows 10 NFS Client?

Tags: nfs, nfsclient

I've already written a working application in AutoIt that will mount and dismount NFS shares using the built-in NFS Client in Windows 10 Pro. The problem is that I've had to hard code the names and paths of the NFS shares exported from the server, and now I want to reduce or eliminate such hard-coding.

My current home network consists of all Windows 10 Pro machines, with no official Windows Server operating system. Instead, the host computer is running the very reliable third-party tool haneWIN NFS Server. Note that it supports NFS 3 but not later versions.

So what I want is to find a way to query the NFS server to discover the exported share names and their read/write status, and any other mandatory information so that I can mount them on the client. And I want to obtain that information over the network using whatever commands are available to provide it, presumably using the unix-compatible commands. I would receive the replies via the standard output stream.

However, I don't know what commands and/or processes could provide that data, nor how to employ  them. Hell, I don't know that what I want to do is even possible.

Would you experts be kind enough to advise or educate me, please?  Thanks!

p.s.: Please try to avoid any language-specific solutions, not even for AutoIt.

I've read and re-read the official Microsoft NFS networking sections of their documentation, but I couldn't find what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

How embarrassing! I continued looking for a solution and found one already on my own [blush].

I just need to issue the following command from the normal CMD processor: "ShowMount -e "

I'm sorry for wasting your time.